# VisualStudio Asp.NET MVC FindAllReferences in .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, refactoring

**Is there a way to find all references of an HTML helper method in the views?**

In VisualStudio, when using the "FindAllReferences" option on a method (or when refactoring), only the references in .cs files are returned, while references in an .aspx page are not found.

NOTE: Using the "Find and Replace" tool is not what I'm looking for.